# Magento 1: cookie update stops the cart from being emptied

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cart, event-observer, session

Here's an interesting one, I have an observer on the `customer_logout` event:

```
<customer_logout>
    <observers>
        <vendor_module_customer_logout>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>updateCartCountCookie</method>
        </vendor_module_customer_logout>
    </observers>
</customer_logout>
```

Then in my observer I have the following:

```
public function updateCartCountCookie(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{      
    Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->set(
        $name       = "cart-count",
        $value      = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(),
        $period     = null, // default 3600
        $path       = "/",
        $domain     = null,
        $secure     = null,
        $httponly   = null
    );
}
```

Following this process:

- (logged out) add stuff to my cart
- login
- items are still in my cart
- logout
- items are still in my cart

Expected result: my cart should be empty, why is it still containing all my items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Bug

Yet **another Magento bug unfortunately**.

The `customer_logout` event is triggered **before the customer is really logged out**:

```
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
        $this->_logout();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Thus when I call `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()`, the following code from `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` is called:

```
public function getSummaryQty()
{
    $quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();

    //If there is no quote id in session trying to load quote
    //and get new quote id. This is done for cases when quote was created
    //not by customer (from backend for example).
    if (!$quoteId && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
    }

    if ($quoteId && $this->_summaryQty === null) {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart_link/use_qty')) {
            $this->_summaryQty = $this->getItemsQty();
        } else {
            $this->_summaryQty = $this->getItemsCount();
        }
    }
    return $this->_summaryQty;
}
```

As **the customer is still logged in** and there is not `$quoteId`, the system gets a new quote by calling `$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();` which basically **retrieves the logged in customer quote**.

### The Solution

The solution is to dispatch the `customer_logout` event **once the customer is logged out**:

```
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_logout();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Even better, the solution the Magento team should implement is to **split the `customer_logout` into two different events**:

```
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('before_customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
        $this->_logout();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('after_customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Unfortunately, M1 reaching is EOL, I highly doubt this will happen.

So the other solution is to **observe the `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout` event instead of `customer_logout`**

Comment: This just seems like a mis-use of stack overflow. You asked the question and answered it in the same minute.

Comment: @ParasSood yep that's the purpose of the "answer my question" checkbox when creating a question. Regarding the use of stackoverflow you can find more details about answering your own question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question